# asp.mvc editable dropdownlist box (combobox)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a solution to an issue I have with a current MVC 4 project I am working on. I would like to have an editable dropdownlist control, or combobox as I think this type of control is sometimes called. Where the control would operate as a typical dropdown control, but allow the user to type in a value that is not present in the dropdown list. I have had no luck with my search so far so I am hoping that this great community of developers could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code for what you have tried so far

Comment: Take a look at [Select2](https://select2.github.io) or jQuery auto complete

Answer (score 2):

If you use HTML then you can use **input** with **datalist** attribute
Example:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" list="valueList"/>
<datalist id="valueList">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Years of working on the web, and never knew about this one! Thanks