# Replace a dropdownlist by a combobox (editable dropdown)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a webpage where I currently use a drop-down list to assist a user when filtering data:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    Sessie datum: <input type="text" id="currentFilterOnSessionDate" class=" form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" name="currentFilterOnSessionDate" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilterOnSessionDate"]"/>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    Discipline: <select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="ViewBag.Disciplines" class=" form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id ="currentFilterOnDiscipline" name="currentFilterOnDiscipline" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilterOnDiscipline"]"></select>    
</div>
```

In some cases I would like to replace this drop-down list with a combo box, allowing the user to select one of the predefined values, or to type one in him- or herself.

I've been googling this, but most examples I seem to find for asp .net core all use 3rd party controls like **Devexpress** or **Telerik**.

The other examples (like [asp.mvc editable dropdownlist box (combobox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046795/asp-mvc-editable-dropdownlist-box-combobox)) I don't really know how to adapt to make work for ASP.NET Core MVC.

Are there any alternatives for combo boxes in classical ASP.NET Core?

The next steps. :-)

Using the answer I received here, and a little bit googling I managed to more or less obtain the result I was looking for.

I do still have a couple of issues.

Let me first start by updating the currently used code. In the html body itself I implemented a the classical **select** like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    Discipline: <select id="disciplineSelect" asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="ViewBag.Disciplines"
                        class=" form-control text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                        id="currentFilterOnDiscipline" 
                        name="currentFilterOnDiscipline"
                        value="@ViewData["CurrentFilterOnDiscipline"]">            
                </select>
</div>
```

Then in the **@section Scripts**, I've added the following code to transform it into a **select2** control:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#disciplineSelect').select2({
        placeholder: "Selecteer een discipline",
        theme: "classic",
        allowClear: true,
    });
</script>
```

This does what I want it to do, but... the layout isn't really 100%:

[image: As loaded]

[image: When used]

What I would like is the 2 controls on the page to have the same height and the combobox spans the width from the start to of the control to the arrow button. As it is now I don't think the client will approve...

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: There is no raw html combo box. An input can have a `list` (&`datalist`) of suggestions which might be enough. Otherwise a fake combo box would involve an `<input`,  `position:relative`, `position:absolute`, javascript event handlers ...

Comment: It's not a complete fit as I explain below. I have been sick most of the week, not been able to return to this project til today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any alternatives for combo boxes in classical asp .net core?

I think you could use Select2.js:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label> Account Number</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select id="mySelect2" class="form-control accountSelect">
            <option value="Select" disabled>Select</option>
            <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
            <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
            <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
            <option value="ddd">ddd</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mySelect2").select2();
        })
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

If your selectlist resource is from the backend,you could change the view like below:

Index.cshtml:

```
@model TestVM
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label> Account Number</label>
    <div class="input-group">
     
        <select id="mySelect2" asp-items="Model.Select" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class TestVM
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Select{ get; set; }     
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = new TestVM()
    {
        Select= new List<SelectListItem>() {
                    new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "aaa" },
                    new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "bbb" },
                    new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "ccc" },
                    new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "ddd" }
                    }
        
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Close. It look better than the classic asp .net listbox, but it does not allow a user to input a value not present in the listing, which is one of the things I've been looking for.

Comment: Combined this with another post and managed to get it working. 

    <script>
        $('#disciplineSelect').select2({
            placeholder: "Selecteer een discipline",
            theme: "bootstrap4",
            allowClear: true,
            tags : true,
        });
    </script>

This allows for the functionality I was looking for. I'll keep on testing it.

Comment: Though I do wonder if there isn't a way to make it visually more appealing.